# problem installing the latest MonoTouch 4.0 update

Tags: xamarin.ios

i have have a problem when I try to run the latest monotouch 4.0 update, the installer starts running the installation and show me a screen about "configuring the installation" then just abort the installation with the screen "Installation Failed". Can anyone help to figure out this problem ? where should i go to see what's my installation problem id ? by the way, I can install monotouch 3.2.6 just fine on my system

Answer (score 1):

May be you file is corrupted and you have to download it another time
be sure that you turned of monodevelop and run then the installation

Comment: I try to download the update package again and it is working now. I guess my last download was somehow corrupted. Thanks for your help

Comment: So You can rate the answer :p

Answer (score 1):

Try making sure you quit the iOS Simulator first. When the simulator is open, many programs fail to install for some reason (regardless of whether they are related to iPhone development or not)